# String pattern, regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I would like to learn something about using `string patterns`.

For an **email** I have that

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-z]+
```

It should be ok, or something to make better? 
I dont want anything complicated, just basic "friendly readable".
Is there any way how to limit email domain for 2-3 chars via expression?

And for URL I've started with something like that

```
^(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-z]+(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)+\\.[a-z_-]+
```

How to extend patter for URL parameters? Like:

```
http://hostname.domain/uriFrag1/uriFrag2/someFilename.fileExt?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Any ideas how to simply make pattern for `?param1=val1&param2=val2`?

There can be parameters, but they aren't mandatory.

Comment: maybe you should do some tutorials or read a book, if you are really interested in how these patterns work ;)

Comment: By the way, [this](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is the regular expression that correctly validates email addresses. Which demonstrates nicely the futility of validating everything with regular expressions. (Or as the author euphemistically puts it: `pushes the limits of what it is sensible to do with regular expressions`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-z]+
```

A few things about this. You should probably also add . and maybe even +, since both are quite common in emails (e.g. Gmail allows both). Secondly you can limit the number of characters with {from-to}. So:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-z]{1,3}
```

However, you might want to consider not doing this since longer domain names has just been sold. People might show up with .cloud or .email emails, and you wouldn't want to turn them away.

As for the url:

?param1=val1 this can easily be matched with

```
(\\?[a-z]*=[a-z]*)*
```

However, if you actually want to get them you might want to use some capture groups.

```
(\\?([a-z]*)=([a-z]*))*
```

Comment: Aww, of course, magic bracket and asterisk for multiplay matches :)
That's exactly, what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: FYI - in java pattern length should be write like this `{1,3}` :)

Comment: You're quite right. Forgot about the java tag.Updated the post.

Comment: and also in string literal to escape `\\` :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing that, I find `split` the simplest one. Since all parameters are passed after the question mark, you can simply:

```
String params = url.split("\\?")[1];
```

It's highly recommended to check the boundaries of the resulted array before trying to access the elements.

Comment: Of course that's the way- split URL string and try to match every single parameter, but question is if there is some straight way how to make it via pattern :) but thank you.